# How to draw abline() that doesn't intersect the Y-axis in R?

Tags: r, axis-labels

I have a location quotient plot drawn in R and want to draw a horizontal line along the plot where Y = 1. I have the code `abline(h=1, col="black")` but when the line is drawn, it intersects the Y-axis and crosses out my Y-axis labels.

Does anyone know how to terminate the line at the Y-axis rather than having it intersect?

Many thanks.

Comment: That doesn't seem like the usual behavior for abline. Have you changed the `xpd=` par option anywhere? For further help, you'll need to edit your question to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that we can run to re-create the problem and find out exactly what's wrong.

Comment: maybe use `segments` from grahics? http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/segments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like the parameter `xpd` has been changed, so one option is to change it back to `FALSE`, see `?par`.  you can control the clipping region using the `clip` function to further limit the range that `abline` and other functions plot within.  This may also be affected by you plotting device (different devices can deal with clipping differently).

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg, changing the xpd back to false worked, that was infuriating me last night! 

Didn't know about the clip function so been having a play around with that.